# How to force Siri to be disabled while the Do Not Disturb mode is on?

Tags: siri, big-sur, do-not-disturb

As the title clearly describes, I want `Siri` to be disabled automatically while the `Do Not Disturb` mode is on. How can I do this?

p.s. I'm on Big Sur.

Comment: Can you clarify why you want Siri to be disabled in this case and be enabled otherwise?

Comment: Because I do not want my lectures to be interrupted by Siri despite not explicitly saying "Hey Siri", and I want to benefit from Siri after my lectures. @JBallin

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Sounds like you want to disable "Hey Siri" in do not disturb (note that this is only available to Macs 2018+), as opposed to disabling Siri completely. I personally keep "Hey Siri" disabled all the time and just use the keyboard shortcut to activate Siri. In your case, it sounds like you still want to retain "Hey Siri" when do not disturb is off, right?

Comment: Thank for your comment, too. Yes, it's what exactly I've been looking for.